# How to add space between UITextField Placeholder characters?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring, placeholder

I want to add Space between `UITextField` `placeHolder` Text.

```
func setTextFieldCharacterSpacing(txtField: TextFieldCustomize) {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txtField.text!)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: CGFloat(8.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    txtField.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

**Edit 1**

I have done this by using `textField` `delegate` method as below.

```
extension LoginVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        CommonHelper.sharedInstance.setTextFieldCharacterSpacing(txtField: textField as! TextFieldCustomize)
        return true
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

I have 1 `textField` with secure entry. when I type anything in that `textField`, `txtField.attributedText`space between characters not applied.

**Without Secure Field**
[image]

**With Secure Field**

[image]

This works for `Username` but not for `password` secure field.

how to add space between characters in secure entry `textField`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using `attributedPlaceholder`?

Comment: because I also want to add space between character in placeholder.

Comment: And what is the output of your code?

Comment: code added in my question is working fine for space between character. but facing error while using this code for `attributedPlaceholder`.

Comment: The secure entry field having the text and others filed having placeholder.

Comment: @TheTiger no no **After String Edit**  `Username` field have `Developer` value and `Password` field have `Developer` value.

Comment: @Kuldeep Would you please mind to give any feedback or accept the answer if your problem has been solved. Or if none of the answers worked for you please post your solution and accept it.

Comment: @TheTiger, in my case, secure text field with custom font doesn't leave space as I want so I remove it and used normal field.

Comment: So I mentioned this in my answer that its not working with custom font. So would you please accept the answer? I also added the custom way to make a secure text entry field. Actually I just want either accept any answer or add your solution and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `attirbutedString` code is okay you're just putting it in wrong property of `textField`. `attributedPlaceholder` is the right one. `attributedText` is used to set the text value not placeholder.

So change

```
txtField.attributedText = attributedString
```

to

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```

**Below is the output:**

[image]

**EDIT: While user is typing**

Add target on `textField` for `editingDidChange` event

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEdidtingDidChange(_ :)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

And here is how can you give space while user is typing.

```
@objc func textFieldEdidtingDidChange(_ textField :UITextField) {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textField.text!)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: CGFloat(8.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    textField.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT: 2**

> After analyzing the demo project provided by @kuldeep it seems `secureTextEntry` is not working if we use `customFont` (other than the system). I tried with `systemFont` and it works and its also working for all fonts if we uncheck the `secureTextEntry`.

I don't know why it spacing is not working in that case but I come up with below solution:

I'm not gonna using `secureTextEntry` instead I will replace all the characters on `editingChange` event. So I created a custom class:

```
class PasswordField: TextFieldCustomize {
    var originalText: String? /// Your original text
    var customChar = "•" /// Custom character to replace with original character while typing
}
/// TextFieldCustomize is a custom class I found in demo project.
```

And here is the updated method for `editingChange:`

```
@objc func textFieldEdidtingDidChange(_ textField :UITextField) {

    var string = textField.text;
    if let passwordField = textField as? PasswordField {
       /// Replace all the characters by custom character •
       var newString = ""
       let count = string?.characters.count ?? 0
       for i in 0..<count {
            if i == count - 1 {
                let lastChar = string!.characters.last!
                newString.append(lastChar)
            }
            else {
                newString.append(passwordField.customChar)
            }
       }
       string = newString

        /// This will be your original text, So use passwordField.originalText instead of passwordField.text when needed
         passwordField.originalText = textField.text
     }

     let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string!)
     attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: CGFloat(8.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
     textField.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but there's 1 `password` filed with `secure entry`, in that field `txtField.attributedText` doesn't work.

Comment: @Kuldeep Please update this in your question too so that we can answer accordingly.

Comment: @Kuldeep You want space in text (when user is typing) or in placeholder?

Comment: **1.** `Username` and `Password` `textField` `placeHolder` spacing is **done**     **2.** `Username` text **(when user is typing or after finish typing) is done**     **3** `Password` text **(when user is typing or after finish typing) NOT WORKING**

Comment: How did you do that for `Username text (when user is typing or after finish typing) is done` ? There is not difference in securetext , It should work.

Comment: I did this by `textField` `delegate` method like this. `extension LoginVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        CommonHelper.sharedInstance.setTextFieldCharacterSpacing(txtField: textField as! TextFieldCustomize)
        return true
    }
}`

Comment: Don't know what are you doing in this method, You should set the `attributedText` and `attributedPlaceholder` for all fields and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not working for password field.

Comment: I don't like its not working. If it will not work I would not answer. I have updated my answer with `gif`.

Comment: I can see it's working from your end but may be I am doing something wrong so it's not working form my end here is demo link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2fzhjn4ebzfwc5/TestDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169410/discussion-between-thetiger-and-kuldeep).

Comment: @Kuldeep Hi, Lets come in chat room regarding your issue.

Comment: @Kuldeep Check **Edit:2**. [Here is your updated demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jna36jha0gqfr8t/TestDemo.zip)

Answer (score 1):

For placeholder you should do it like this,

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txtField.placeholder!)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: CGFloat(8.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
txtField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```

If you have not set placeholder text in `storyboard` then you should also set its value before calling the above snippet,

```
txtField.placeholder = "Developer"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want left padding in TextField just use below code, it'll add padding to the left for placeholder as well as text

```
txtField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

The amount of left padding you can change by changing the value of at first argument .

### Edit

If you want space between characters, why don't you use `attributedPlaceholder` property? I tried your code with `attributedPlaceholder`, and it works perfectly.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Developer")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: CGFloat(8.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
txtField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```

Comment: This code only add Leading space between placeholder but I want to add space between `textField` every character. suppose `textField` text is `Developer` than I want `D e v e l o p e r`.

Comment: Why don't you use `attributedPlaceholder`?